# Add css class to element if sibling div exists

Tags: html, css

When `button` with class `menu-button` is clicked, `div` with class `popover-menu` is added to the `DOM`. When this happens, the `popover-menu` element becomes `active`.

Is there a way using `CSS` to add an additional class to the `button` whenever `popover-menu` is within `DOM`?

```
<div>
  <button class="menu-button">
    <span>Clickme</span>
  </button>
  <div class="popover-menu">
    Menu
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just add the class to `.menu-button` when the `.popover-menu` is added to the DOM (through JS, I presume)?

Comment: I want the class that was added to be removed when `<div class="popover-menu">` is removed or does not exist

Comment: You cannot use CSS to "add an additional class". If your DOM elements were differently ordered, you could use CSS selectors, but in this case, you'll need to use JavaScript. Post your JavaScript code for adding and removing `.popover-menu`, as that'd be the most logical place to add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no ability to mutate an element's classes within the context of a stylesheet, in your case the `only-child` pseudo-class may suffice for what you want to do here.

```
<style>
  .menu-button:only-child {
    color: pink;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <button class="menu-button">
    <span>Clickme</span>
  </button>
  <div class="popover-menu">
    Menu
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/hamzatayeb/pen/dzKyja